# Simplify template usage by removing array

Tags: templates, go, go-templates

I am trying to simplify the template which I use to make it use a flatter data structure:

from

```
data := []App{App{"test data", []string{"app1", "app2", "app3"}}}
```

To:

```
data := App{App{"test data", []string{"app1", "app2", "app3"}}}
```

i.e. Remove the array of `App`, but when I try it I get an error.

Here is the working version: https://play.golang.org/p/2THGtDvlu01

I tried to change the template to

```
{{ range . -}}
{range $i,$a := .Command}{{if gt $i 0 }} && {{end}}{{.}}{{end}}
{{end}}
```

But I got an error of `type mismatched`, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    // Define a template.
    const tmpl = `
echo &1

{{range $i,$a := .Command}}{{if gt $i 0 }} && {{end}}{{.}}{{end}}

echo 2
`

    // Prepare some data
    type App struct {
        Data    string
        Command []string
    }
    data := App{"test data", []string{"app1", "app2", "app3"}}

    // Create a new template and parse into it.
    t := template.Must(template.New("tmpl").Parse(tmpl))

    // Execute the template with data
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("executing template:", err)
    }

}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/OwysCnIhhOV)

Gives the output

```
echo &1

app1 && app2 && app3

echo 2

Program exited.
```

If you remove the `[]App` from your code, you also need to remove the `range` used in the template.